# Call C# Add-in from Visio double click event

Tags: c#, add-in, visio

I am tring to call with **=CALLTHIS("pp",)** and with **=CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.pp",)** from shape event dblClick. I´m using C# Visio 2010 Add-in in Visual Studio 2015 without success.

The method is:

```
     public static void pp(Visio.Shape shpObj) {
         MessageBox.Show("My id is: " + shpObj.ID);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a managed C# (VSTO/COM) add-in from shape sheet formula cell, such as "dblClick" event, use QUEUEMARKEREVENT function. CALLTHIS only works for VBA functions. RUNADDON/RUNADDONWARGS only works for unmanaged (VSL) addons.

Here you can find a step-by-step guide how to make it happen:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chcast/2004/11/03/calling-com-add-ins-from-the-shapesheet/